# Term for changing a word to fit another word inside it

Tags: vocabulary, linguistics

Ska does this all the time.

The Skatalites 
Eskanol (spanish ska)
Skatastrophic

I can't seem to think of a single other example, but I know I've seen it other places.

Comment: Compounding? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)

Comment: This is not a compound. Probably not even a portmanteau, as for that the meaning would have to change, though your examples are very unclear in that regard (what *do* all these words mean?). This looks like just a word play, nothing more.

Comment: This is the greatest board ever. Can't believe there's answers already.
So, they're just names. Ive always thought it might be a sort of marketing ploy. My roommate informs me that the porn industry does this quite a bit as well.

Comment: Actually portmanteau gets pretty close. Spork: Spoon+fork. Skatastrophic: Ska and Catastrophic. But yeah, wordplays come into this too. I wanted to play in a band called the Skandinavians :)

Comment: That is a fantastic band name. FANTASTIC. My imaginary chick punk band is called Juicy Jenny and the Infected Vas Deferens. :)

Comment: The point about portmanteaus is, they must not only superficially merge words or morphemes, but also their meanings. *Smog* is not just a word play on *smoke* and *fog*, it actually *means* something. Same for *spork*. It's not just a word played for laughs, it actually is useful with a clear accepted meaning. Does *skatastrophic* mean anything at all? Is it an established term? Or is it just, well, a word play?

Answer (score 1):

The phrase “changing a word to fit another word inside it” is suggestive of *[tmesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis)*, which is “a linguistic phenomenon in which a word or phrase is separated into two parts, with other words interrupting between them”.  Further from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmesis):

> [Some] tmesis involves the insertion of a word or phrase into another word, for added emphasis and often for humorous effect. The insertion may occur between the parts of a compound word, or between syllable boundaries (dystmesis), but always preceding a stressed syllable (e.g. one would never say, “Ab-bloody-solutely”, preferring “Abso-bloody-lutely”). It is also sometimes referred to as *tumbarumba*, possibly due to the popularity of tmesis in Australian English dialect (Tumbarumba, New South Wales being an Australian town), or possibly due to the poem “Tumba Bloody Rumba” by John O’Grady, which includes several tmeses including “Tumba-bloody-rumba”, “e-bloody-nough”, and “kanga-bloody-roos”.

Comment: Hah, I was hoping nobody would go down that route. OP's phrase you quoted suggests tmesis alright, but his examples are really nothing of that sort. "Ska" is not really inserted in *catastrophic*, only the s- is. It's also not inserted before the stressed syllable. And in "Eskanol" nothing is inserted at all, but rather a letter is changed.